# Hosting Eclipse Program inside C# Program

Tags: c#, eclipse, host

I am a new C# programmer.
I want to host eclipse program in my C# program, so user will open my program and inside it will be eclipse program all it in one window. I try the following code, it is work for nodepad program but not eclipse

```
        Process proc;

        // Start the process
        proc = Process.Start("C:\\eclipse/eclipse.exe");
        proc.WaitForInputIdle();

        // Set the panel control as the application's parent
        SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, this.panel1.Handle);

        // Maximize application
        SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, 274, 61488, 0);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe","/C "+fileZillaPath + "\\\"FileZilla Server.exe\" /reload-config"); This code has worked for me before, Notice there are 2 arguments the first being CMD.exe and the second being the path. I think the /C was also important

Comment: I want to add some point to the question. The code is open the eclipse program but not in same same windows like do in notepad. It open eclipse in other window . Sorry for do not say that.

Answer (score 0):

try this one Process.Start(@"eclipsePath/eclipse.exe",@"your file path")